# How does React remove asynchronous behavior?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have been reading [this](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Motivation.html), and I came across a line in the Redux documentation

> Libraries like React attempt to solve this problem in the view layer
>   by removing both asynchrony and direct DOM manipulation.

I understood the part where React does not allow DOM manipulations as it abstracts the actual rendering using the `render()` method. I am confused with the second part.

How does React remove the asynchrony? Can someone please explain with examples or valid use cases.

Comment: I think it removes async DOM manipulation by using Virtual DOM... so it does things before it changes the real DOM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It removes asynchronous behavior from the **view layer** by design. You must not do async stuff in `render` or what is rendered will be broken.

> Libraries like React attempt to solve this problem in the **view layer** 
>   by removing both asynchrony and direct DOM manipulation [from the `render` method].

You are missing the last sentence which gives further explanations:

> However, managing the state of your data is left up to you. 
>   This is where Redux enters.

To wrap up, there **must** be no async calls in render method but there can be some async stuff happening in the *state management* part handled by Redux. You can't do async stuff in the render method by design. If you you do so it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that good example would be an rendering library like dust.js
It renders template asynchronous, creates document fragment, and let user handle appending in callback.

And well... I think that any DOM mutations performed in callbacks counts into this case.